# How to enrich JSON array in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I get a set of JSONs in a loop and want to build an array from them(studentArray). Either the predefined 'studentArray' array or a totally new one would be fine. Couldn't find in any examples or docs.

```
        json studentArray = [];

        foreach i, x in studentInfoXml.selectDescendants("student").elements(){

            json studentResponseJson = getStudentJson(x);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found was to assign each value through an explicit index.

```
    json studentArray = [];

    foreach i, x in studentInfoXml.selectDescendants("student").elements(){
        json studentResponseJson = getStudentJson(x);
        studentArray[studentArray.count()] = studentResponseJson;
    }
```

Comment: Answer is working fine in methods. I found an issue while using it in a service and reported https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/9291#issuecomment-401302913